# How Can I minimize the HTML code by making it one line of code?

Tags: html, css, line, javascript, minimization

So I have made a web page of HTML, Inline CSS and JS. Since this page will be produced through JS function

```
 opened.document.write();
```

I would like to put all the web page code into one line that can be taken in one of the previously mention function instead of repeating the same function for every new line. I can't affors doing this manually,because the page contains too many lines of code.

Is there a fast and clean way to do this?

**Notice:** I used *SOME PROGRAM* to replace all " with \" by one click, so I hope there is away to replace all the(Enter)s with (Backspace) or something like that.

---

**Elaboration**

I want to produce the whole page when the user click on a button which will call a JS function which will produce a new page and write it using the previously mentioned function.

Comment: You used *MS Word* to edit code?

Comment: Whitespace is mostly ignored when rendering html, so what's your reason to for this?

Comment: I suggest notepad++ instead of word. Word is NOT for coding Mak..

Comment: From MS Word you should leap right into vim or emacs. Either you'll turn out really good, or go batshit insane---I give it 50/50.

Comment: MAK: Based on your elaboration, why are you even using word then? You're hard-coding the HTML you want it to produce? Well, then, as advised, use a proper text editor to get it in the correct format. But if you want to write out a segment of the already-existing page again, note you can get that with the '.innerHTML' property, if it interests you.

Comment: Ben James: Yes I used MS Word to edit code. I know it's not safe and dangerous due to the hidden code that is produced by WORD but I know how to handle it, don't worry! :)
Jimmy Shelter: White space yes, but the "enter" no!
JohnnyArt: I know, it just this is what I found ready at the moment! :)

Comment: Aren't there libraries that will minify code for you? I know that there are for JS, why not HTML? I'm pretty sure I've seen google's markup minified at some point.

Comment: Silky: I just want a way to make my code appear on one line!
SapphireSun: Let me know if you find anything interesting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm, well the answer is "Yes", but it's slightly disturbing what you are doing.

I don't know if you can replace special characters in Word, but in most text editors (Textpad, Notepad++) you can replace via a 'regex' so you can write "\r\n" to replace all instances of newlines with whatever you wish.

I must say, though, that I wonder why you wish to write out the document like that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: thanks Silky, but what If I want to replace it with nothing? meaning get rid of it?

Comment: In those editors, you just leave the thing to replace it with as blank. It deletes it.

Comment: I tried notepad and Wordpad!
I can't install any programs on this machine, Any Suggestions?

Comment: Neither Notepad or Wordpad will do it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [online text editor with regex](http://myregexp.com/), paste your code in and fix up some regex to replace \r and \n with a whitespace or no spaces. I don't know regex so you'll have to do it or ask for it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your HTML pages to be generated by Javascript is a Very Bad Idea. You're making your entire website virtually invisible to Search Engines, users with javascript off, and those using screen readers, and for what benefit? Saving a couple of hundred bytes? Set up your webserver with gzip compression and proper cache control and leave the source as is.

Comment: Hi nickf, 
1- It's not meant for this page to be found on Search engines.
2- Size was never an issue.
I need to do this task as I specified, because this is the best solution for my case. No point of me explaining the whole case if all what I need  is what i mentioned in my question...So...Any suggestions?

Comment: I still think the point still stands that there's no excuse for hiding your content.